# Extract Specific Dates from DateList

Tags: list-manipulation, date-and-time

Hopefully this is an easy question but I couldn't find an easy answer anyway. Surely there is some simple way to splice this...

I want to take a large datelist in the format of {{2014,12,31}, value} and extract only the first date of every year. Here is the code that generates a date list:

```
sampleDates = Thread[
   {DateRange[{2010, 1, 1}, {2014, 12, 31}], 
    RandomFunction[RandomWalkProcess[0.5], {1825}]["Values"]}
   ];
DateListPlot[sampleDates]
```

How can I obtain a list which is just

```
{ {2010,1,1}, 0}, {2011,1,1}, 10}, {2012,1,1}, 23} ... }
```

from the sampleDates set above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like to try to use the new `TimeSeries` functionality when possible. This works by first rescaling the time range to use actual dates rather than integer time stamps and then picks out only those dates we are interested in.

```
data = RandomFunction[RandomWalkProcess[0.5], {1825}];
ts = TimeSeriesRescale[data, {{2010, 1, 1}, {2014, 12, 31}, "Day"}];
jan1 = TimeSeriesResample[ts, {{2010, 1, 1}, {2014, 12, 31}, "Year"}];

DateListPlot[{ts, jan1}, Joined -> {True, False}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Automatic, {Red, PointSize[.025], Opacity[.5]}}]
```

[image]

Note that you could use the explicit list of dates rather than the `{tmin, tmax, dt}` specification when resampling but I find this more concise in this particular case.

Answer (score 5):

```
newyearF = Pick[#,{##2}=={1,1}&@@@#[[All,1]]]&;


sampleDates = Thread[
   {DateRange[{2010, 1, 1}, {2014, 12, 31}], 
    RandomFunction[RandomWalkProcess[0.5], {1825}]["Values"]}
   ];

newyearF @ sampleDates
(* {{{2010,1,1},0}, {{2011,1,1},-1}, {{2012,1,1},-20}, {{2013,1,1},-48}, {{2014,1,1},-11}} *)
```

To see the selected dates in `DateListPlot`, you can use

```
DateListPlot[{sampleDates,newyearF@sampleDates},
             Joined->{True,False},
             PlotStyle->{Automatic,Directive[{PointSize[Large],Red}]},
             GridLines->{newyearF[sampleDates][[All,1]],None}]
```

or

```
DateListPlot[sampleDates,
             GridLines->{newyearF[sampleDates][[All,1]],None},
             Mesh->{AbsoluteTime/@newyearF[sampleDates][[All,1]]},
             MeshStyle->Directive[{PointSize[Large],Red}]]
```

[image]

**Update:** The function `TimeSeriesResample` used in Andy's answer is not available for version 9. An alternative is to use the functions `TemporalData` and `` TemporalData`Resample ``:

```
tdResample = TemporalData`Resample;

dates = {{2010, 1, 1}, {2015, 1, 1}};
times = {DateRange @@ dates};
data = RandomFunction[RandomWalkProcess[0.5], {DateDifference @@ dates}];
td = TemporalData[data["States"], times];
td2 = tdResample[td, {1, "Year"}];

DateListPlot[{td["Path"], td2["Path"]}, Joined -> {True, False}, 
           PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Directive[PointSize[Large], Red]}]
```

[image]

Comment: This plot is super cool. Thanks for doing the extra work!

Comment: @Tom, my pleasure. Happy new year..

Comment: @TomHayden Are neither solutions worthy of your acceptance?

Comment: Oops, sorry for the delay there, guys! Thanks for these awesome answers. I picked the time series one because it's the most familiar tool that I know.. but I guess all of these are right. Mathematica SE is the best.

Answer (score 3):

```
Select[sampleDates, #[[1, 2]] == #[[1, 3]] == 1 &]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a simple pattern match i.e

```
Cases[sampleDates, {{_, 1, 1}, _}, 2]
```